# p2-maven-plugin fails with hadoop

Tags: maven, hadoop, p2

If I include hadoop-annotations as a (transitive) dependency, running p2-maven-plugin with `mvn p2:site` fails:

```
[info] Executing Bundler:
[info]   [EXEC] hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar
[warn]  : Superfluous export-package instructions: [org.apache, org.apache.hadoop.io.file, org]
[info] Executing Bundler:
[info]   [EXEC] hadoop-annotations-2.7.1.jar
[warn]  : Superfluous export-package instructions: [org.apache.hadoop, org, org.apache]
[info] Executing Bundler:
[info]   [EXEC] tools.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.235 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-01-06T13:09:37+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/303M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.reficio:p2-maven-plugin:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT:site (default-cli) on project com.incquerylabs.capellabenchmark.dependencies: Execution default-cli of goal org.reficio:p2-maven-plugin:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT:site failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while bundling jar or source: tools.jar: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../lib/tools.jar.78edbbdc-bfbf-46f3-8f9b-35681a60baf5 (Permission denied) -> [Help 1]
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

hadoop-annotations depends on a JDK jar:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
  <version>1.6</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

You have to exclude this in the p2-maven-plugin configuration:

```
<artifact>
    <id>{artifact that depends on hadoop-annotations}</id>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>jdk.tools:jdk.tools</exclude> <!-- workaround for hadoop-annotations -->
    </excludes>
</artifact>
```